# Unable to get value as per My ID get all database data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to edit my form so I want `data` to be the `id` which I selected, but I do not get `data` as per my requirement.

JSON error screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdkuX.jpg

Ajax Code:

```
var url = document.URL;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  data: id,
  url: 'get.php',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
});
```

get.php

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) 
{
  $getUsers = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE id = '".$_POST['data']."'");
  $getUsers->execute();

  $users = $getUsers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($users);
}
```

Comment: sorry Did not get any data and get JSON input error check url https://imgur.com/a/vD2fKpK

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use prepared statements as your current logic is *wide open* for SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==> WHILE POST DATA using ajax to Php page we must be use key/Value Pair. other wise it not received on php page.

Comment: This is what my answer states.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the content of the AJAX request as a plain string. You need to send it as a key/value pair. The easiest way to do that is to provide an object to `data`, like this:

```
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
$.ajax({
  data: { data: id },
  // other properties...
});
```

Also note that you should remove the `$.parseJSON(data)` line in the `success` handler. It will cause an error as jQuery will already deserialise the response for you.

Comment: i cant solve my issue, i got two error  check screen shot https://imgur.com/a/MgALcJl